# angularjs ignored added headers

Tags: angularjs, xmlhttprequest

i am tyring to get google api token by sendding auth code to google following [this guide](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp).

this is my code:

```
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
            params : {
                code           : '4/heMv6ozWwCxS5RyTzCgThAgxvRyk.oske-bNEGOUTOl05ti8ZT3YnwwH8iQI',
                client_id      : GoogleAppInfo.clientId,
                 redirect_uri  : GoogleAppInfo.redirect_uri,
                client_secret  : GoogleAppInfo.client_secret,
                grant_type     : 'authorization_code'
            }

        }).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert('secsses');
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert('error');

        });
```

the reuqest sended but the header is not set!
[image]

has anyone know what is the problem?

Comment: did you really send it? It looks like you're sending a cross-domain request.

Comment: yes. i sent the request, this is from firefox console after i got the bad response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: [Angular, content type is not being sent with $http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194442/angular-content-type-is-not-being-sent-with-http)

"You need to include a body with the request. Angular removes the content-type header otherwise.

Add `data: ''` to the argument to `$http`."

Comment: thanks! that worked. the header was added. but it didnt solve the problem. google server still retirives bad request eror.

Comment: I suggest adding another question perhaps with different tags now that the problem has shifted to communicating with the google server. I do not have experience with that, sorry.

Comment: well i have dont that. thanks for the help. my other question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22661673/cant-get-access-token-from-google-using-angularjs