# Do I need to account for the "jsonFlickrApi" that is in front of the json returned in my network call?

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit, retrofit2

Building an app and using the retrofit library for android, with gson. When I test the api call in my browser the json returned looks like:

```
jsonFlickrApi({"photos":{"page":1,"pages":10,"perpage":100,"total":1000,"photo":[{"id":"35675834364","owner":"137412266@N06","secret":"3d964c6b5e","server":"4348","farm":5,"title":"Railpage Albion Camera #3 Rail Movement Detection","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"35675835204","owner":"56502036@N04","secret":"cf5e58b4a7","server":"4409","farm":5,"title":"Nanea","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"35675836224","owner":"28512232@N08","secret":"87f3c49985","server":"4431","farm":5,"title":"image","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"35675840884","owner":"150792293@N08","secret":"189b1b0637","server":"4398","farm":5,"title":"Anyone want to lick it? (m)","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"35675841714","owner":"144353406@N05","secret":"fce51dc5d8","server":"4376","farm":5,"title":"Utopya Mercan Hotel","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"35675843464","owner":"147557049@N04","secret":"3e694626ca","server":"4334","farm":5,"title":"","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"35675843794","owner":"129912902@N02","secret":"a7855cfb51","server":"4381","farm":5,"title":"2017-08-12_05-46-57","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"35675850354","owner":"34720151@N02","secret":"de0fff1c84","server":"4331","farm":5,"title":"IMG_0520.jpg","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"35675852724","owner":"151256206@N06","secret":"1d05961d91","server":"4340","farm":5,"title":"Handed out three door hangers","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"35675853994","owner":"153609437@N08","secret":"9d1376db19","server":"4368","farm":5,"title":"Trendy High Heels For You : Casadei | Resort 2015...","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"35675854524","owner":"128042581@N03","secret":"cc1c8ae1c3","server":"4353","farm":5,"title":"My babies on black :)","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"35675856384","owner":"151504840@N02","secret":"6cbd83372d","server":"4413","farm":5,"title":"Dark","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"35675856484","owner":"54575004@N06","secret":"fe18135d87","server":"4411","farm":5,"title":"20170811190601","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"35675856824","owner":"131764115@N03","secret":"6bda9fbd36","server":"4375","farm":5,"title":"36635","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"35675856994","owner":"44722273@N08","secret":"c2e6a90824","server":"4441","farm":5,"title":"New York, New York!","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"35675857514","owner":"89357279@N08","secret":"d45bce7246","server":"4408","farm":5,"title":"KH1_7795.jpg","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"35675858194","owner":"150287976@N06","secret":"dac0570a20","server":"4405","farm":5,"title":"vincent_academy-82017.jpg","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"35702004683","owner":"151438119@N02","secret":"80b4dfb4f7","server":"4390","farm":5,"title":"2017-08-12_03-15-43","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"35702008133","owner":"130227215@N03","secret":"0eeedfa401","server":"4339","farm":5,"title":"Maroon_Bells00026-Edit.jpg","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"35702009693","owner":"150187456@N07","secret":"e765000d86","server":"4343","farm":5,"title":"A better way to build your business: Ask For the Connection, Not the Sale https:\/\/t.co\/lN55rgbsTn via @betterwedding https:\/\/t.co\/wJaP0Hskfm","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"35702010683","owner":"148523190@N02","secret":"e854c6d837","server":"4339","farm":5,"title":"Cheap 48\u2033 Solid Teak Indoor Outdoor Bench Shower Stool \u2013 From the Aqua Stratus Collection","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"35702012383","owner":"148980001@N04","secret":"f8e8872352","server":"4414","farm":5,"title":"Perros para adoptar \u00bb Barcelona \u00bb TULA \u00bb Nom: Tula Sexe: Femella Edat: 4 anys Creuada La Tula \u00e9s una gossa tranquila, molt bona i carinyosa ja que li encanten el...","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"35702015983","owner":"157509849@N03","secret":"a046628acc","server":"4351","farm":5,"title":"Laura Fern\u00e1ndez S\u00e1nchez. 10-3. 08\/08\/2017. 3:13pm. San Carlos. #fotoscoop103 @marthaYfotografias","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"35702019203","owner":"155275835@N05","secret":"99abb5e276","server":"4438","farm":5,"title":"Benimsin 27.B\u00f6l\u00fcm izle 12 A\u011fustos 2017","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"35702023703","owner":"134714797@N06","secret":"5b36e23d01","server":"4359","farm":5,"title":"Grillin' 'n chillin' on the patio this evening! \ud83d\ude4c\ud83d\ude18\ud83c\udfb6\ud83d\udcf1\ud83d\ude0e","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"35702025733","owner":"147629727@N08","secret":"673c5ee312","server":"4412","farm":5,"title":"memories, Davenport, California https:\/\/t.co\/6qGOAYzUTy","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"35702026153","owner":"144651485@N07","secret":"6cfdc09507","server":"4355","farm":5,"title":"2017-08-12_07-17-24","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"35702027733","owner":"123640584@N04","secret":"c2f5649a58","server":"4439","farm":5,"title":"3\u00b0 Semin\u00e1rio Leis B\u00edblicas do Sucesso e Prosperidade de Deus - Voto com Sabedoria Divina - 04 de Julho de 2017.","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"35702028143","owner":"99310838@N07","secret":"70d30f3feb","server":"4423","farm":5,"title":"Les #statues de #ansecaffard #ansecaffardmemorial #laurentvalere #artiste #artist #sculpture #memorial #slave #slavery #esclavage #traitenegriere #lediamant #martinique #martiniquefwi #fwi #caribbean #caribbeansea #naufrage #boisdebene #blackmen #blackand","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"35702028263","owner":"62797411@N02","secret":"5297d47848","server":"4381","farm":5,"title":"\u6570\u5e74\u5f8c\uff08\u9858\u671b\uff09","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"35702032053","owner":"145500891@N02","secret":"212edb8d0e","server":"4365","farm":5,"title":"\u4f5b\u5178\u683c\u8a00 \u751f\u6d3b\u7ae0 \u5e2b\u53cb 3.5.14 \u64c7\u5176\u5584\u8005\u5f9e\u4e4b\uff0c\u60e1\u8005\u9060\u96e2\u4e4b\u3002 \u6211\u8207\u5584\u77e5\u8b58\u76f8\u96a8\uff0c\u81ea\u81f4\u6210\u4f5b\u3002 \u300a\u9f8d\u85cf54\u518a0551\uff1a\u5c38\u8fe6\u7f85\u8d8a\u516d\u65b9\u79ae\u7d93\u300b","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"35702032423","owner":"149739395@N06","secret":"9cb1304734","server":"4403","farm":5,"title":"1502497074-thuong-nhan-trung-quoc-lai-gio-tro-voi-thi-truong-ho-tieu-thoi-su","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"35702033373","owner":"145355663@N04","secret":"73404fa976","server":"4331","farm":5,"title":"Brittany","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"35702033483","owner":"150725490@N07","secret":"eeb8994f81","server":"4363","farm":5,"title":"Europa!","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"35702033813","owner":"15492105@N06","secret":"119e7582ef","server":"4345","farm":5,"title":"","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"35702034993","owner":"55289779@N00","secret":"60dcef4e71","server":"4362","farm":5,"title":"Detail of excavation, SE corner of Victoria and Richmond, 2017 08 11 -f","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36113989280","owner":"40138196@N08","secret":"cc7c304221","server":"4427","farm":5,"title":"Q8100603.jpg","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36113991370","owner":"146263700@N02","secret":"af208765d5","server":"4434","farm":5,"title":"Saint Paul the Apostle\u2019s Travels Ancient Greek and Roman Biblical Historical Coins","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36113993780","owner":"25820099@N08","secret":"225efa5efd","server":"4362","farm":5,"title":"Impatient kitty.","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36113995300","owner":"146059980@N07","secret":"6fe46a71d0","server":"4380","farm":5,"title":"Ove_Rehn-6361.jpg","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36113999520","owner":"113213043@N02","secret":"f6f7ef2d7d","server":"4432","farm":5,"title":"Oklahoma hidden figure: Cherokee woman helped NASA put man on the moon","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36114007220","owner":"47824839@N03","secret":"164a808b29","server":"4359","farm":5,"title":"Dezodorantas STR8 \"On the Edge\" Pour Homme 150ml | 5201314048862","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36114007380","owner":"156621534@N02","secret":"245d476691","server":"4358","farm":5,"title":"Portrait Photography Inspiration : The Fit-And-Flare Wedding Dress from Martina Liana is stunning....","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36114011820","owner":"46819365@N05","secret":"26774aa194","server":"4355","farm":5,"title":"County","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36114012600","owner":"152347436@N06","secret":"ff4525ac1d","server":"4391","farm":5,"title":"Pregnancy Full Body Workouts : The motivation and guidelines you need to start exercising during pregnancy. 14 ...","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36114012950","owner":"157568056@N07","secret":"8e9be3493a","server":"4419","farm":5,"title":"8269644874","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36114013520","owner":"106459535@N07","secret":"c1516477cf","server":"4432","farm":5,"title":"New Baby 2017","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36342445372","owner":"149054924@N06","secret":"6d7d112106","server":"4435","farm":5,"title":"Braun Series 3-350cc Shaver System, Dark Blue For Sale","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36342449602","owner":"110266203@N05","secret":"de9d481076","server":"4342","farm":5,"title":"2017-08-11 18.58.56","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36342451532","owner":"134340137@N02","secret":"8e5d01b662","server":"4342","farm":5,"title":"Untitled","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36342456902","owner":"49118647@N08","secret":"ccdbd95989","server":"4382","farm":5,"title":"CamGrab [LW2.20170812010120.jpg]","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36342459012","owner":"85132042@N06","secret":"6643184b35","server":"4371","farm":5,"title":"1\/2\" foam board printing","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36342459202","owner":"151241830@N04","secret":"dc21776451","server":"4416","farm":5,"title":"Central Park lakes and boating","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36342460242","owner":"100201230@N02","secret":"537881cdb9","server":"4401","farm":5,"title":"\u00a1#AVANZA #HOY! Puedes hacerlo inscribi\u00e9ndote en uno de los 10 Colegios Comunitarios de Maricopa para obtener un dipl\u00f3ma o certificado, \u00f3 para transferirte a la universidad @maricopacc \ud83d\udc49www.maricopa.edu\/ :) #SI a TU FUTURO ;) #EstudiaHOY #GozaM","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36342464602","owner":"132791403@N08","secret":"f50a43a4ba","server":"4405","farm":5,"title":"IP Camera E-mail Alert-md snap(2017-08-12 09:17:24)","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36342464812","owner":"56276949@N03","secret":"739817f6c6","server":"4395","farm":5,"title":"S17_5865","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36342466502","owner":"22464562@N00","secret":"dba60cf7d6","server":"4427","farm":5,"title":"P7220385.jpg","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36342469162","owner":"137909748@N08","secret":"d8f27bb7ea","server":"4392","farm":5,"title":"IMG-20170804-WA0005","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36373371041","owner":"89214878@N00","secret":"0ec75a076e","server":"4418","farm":5,"title":"Photo","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36373371311","owner":"51393291@N02","secret":"64affded6c","server":"4431","farm":5,"title":"Nilo E cortando el pasto de su casa","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36373375201","owner":"53685449@N00","secret":"e5d7fe3ef6","server":"4375","farm":5,"title":"#nybg #newyorkbotanicalgarden #nybgchihuly #dalechihuly #glassart #ig_nycity","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36373377601","owner":"123455135@N05","secret":"c5ef48239c","server":"4383","farm":5,"title":"Teknoloji","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36373380731","owner":"153621373@N04","secret":"b786d7ec0b","server":"4422","farm":5,"title":"kepoo","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36373380861","owner":"130774101@N06","secret":"851e614389","server":"4366","farm":5,"title":"All Set Up For Woodstock 2017","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36373385941","owner":"131866356@N02","secret":"9d23e9a3ae","server":"4408","farm":5,"title":"\u6c34\u5cb8\u6668\u66e6","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36373386001","owner":"145723381@N07","secret":"fe08d58f8d","server":"4402","farm":5,"title":"Win Star Wars Battlefront 2 for PS4 Giveaway 2017","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36373386661","owner":"8581420@N08","secret":"d657f70b60","server":"4390","farm":5,"title":"IMG_2008","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36373396381","owner":"62991404@N06","secret":"c3c85836f9","server":"4441","farm":5,"title":"Record by Always E-mail, 2017-08-11 19:17:23","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36373399261","owner":"147968382@N04","secret":"9753b61be3","server":"4409","farm":5,"title":"Eastern Black Swallowtail caterpillar","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36373401301","owner":"63653206@N02","secret":"7ca0caca1c","server":"4386","farm":5,"title":"DSC03626","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36373402331","owner":"85759026@N00","secret":"cdc1e8cdca","server":"4436","farm":5,"title":"IMG_0764","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36373405301","owner":"32192899@N06","secret":"ed0caa539f","server":"4351","farm":5,"title":"POEMIM","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36464209976","owner":"126711996@N02","secret":"21682796dd","server":"4339","farm":5,"title":"20170811_183224","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36464210316","owner":"44124342631@N01","secret":"bf9711ffa5","server":"4423","farm":5,"title":"Ribeira, Porto","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36464215076","owner":"25030195@N08","secret":"6f6f136870","server":"4384","farm":5,"title":"","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36464219106","owner":"155957343@N02","secret":"102c3353fe","server":"4342","farm":5,"title":"What do you see? \/ O que voc\u00ea v\u00ea?","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36464219376","owner":"8945641@N02","secret":"71729abdfd","server":"4396","farm":5,"title":"Tibetan Prayer wheel \u8f49\u7d93\u8f2a","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36464219956","owner":"74939715@N05","secret":"199a9f2b8a","server":"4334","farm":5,"title":"Cresting over the pier","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36464222206","owner":"79767616@N02","secret":"51f1a65b7a","server":"4419","farm":5,"title":"CCRTA Bus","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36510576775","owner":"86868343@N00","secret":"74e7e01a1b","server":"4350","farm":5,"title":"Tournament Anniversary","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36510577405","owner":"149567335@N07","secret":"44f48c8da5","server":"4381","farm":5,"title":"D-2017-08-12-0915_f","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36510578295","owner":"23706567@N06","secret":"e4ba45a8d2","server":"4361","farm":5,"title":"#Repost @_ozabell_ \u30fb\u30fb\u30fb ahHHh my ink refills and a couple new copic markers came in today from @otakufuel! This is the second time I've ordered from them and I'm very very happy~ fast shipping, everything came all safe a secure in a small package, just gre","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36510578735","owner":"144770144@N06","secret":"9e6577a725","server":"4438","farm":5,"title":"Details... \ud83d\udc2d  #brothers #brotherhood #me #mood #giovanninamio #like #life #bro #nofilter #love #live #friday #fridaymood #we #dance #smile #wecan #lovehim #mylife #everything #say #londonlife #london #today #instaday #instapic #instagood","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36510578855","owner":"152191467@N03","secret":"2183812b8a","server":"4407","farm":5,"title":"\u00a9Nazim","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36510579965","owner":"146142641@N04","secret":"980e4fa9d6","server":"4384","farm":5,"title":"CULTS","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36510580965","owner":"11343593@N06","secret":"b00ff81f8e","server":"4341","farm":5,"title":"V and A Pink Floyd  0057","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36510583455","owner":"20760617@N08","secret":"a0c178b0c9","server":"4376","farm":5,"title":"Sheppard 1973","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36510584875","owner":"60602738@N05","secret":"d547b63316","server":"4404","farm":5,"title":"Light after the rain","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36510589725","owner":"33729495@N03","secret":"a122cc66ef","server":"4415","farm":5,"title":"170810_XF23_XT20_07","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36510590765","owner":"14875393@N02","secret":"dfe5324c5d","server":"4415","farm":5,"title":"51 Monterey bike ride with DAD 2014.jpg","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36510593095","owner":"140009453@N04","secret":"1b3ed48095","server":"4402","farm":5,"title":"","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36510594105","owner":"22797677@N00","secret":"1c2c7232cb","server":"4407","farm":5,"title":"_MG_2633.jpg","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36510600275","owner":"156593494@N02","secret":"57290c33cf","server":"4400","farm":5,"title":"Whatcha lookin' at? \ud83d\udc25","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36510601135","owner":"39267804@N05","secret":"294176e7e3","server":"4398","farm":5,"title":"La Martorana - 12th Century Norman church in Palermo, Sicily - Italy 2016","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36510601585","owner":"153686682@N04","secret":"140c96c75d","server":"4386","farm":5,"title":"Its me","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36510602175","owner":"58530127@N05","secret":"ae17c5ba4e","server":"4341","farm":5,"title":"IMG_1856","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36510603805","owner":"52133204@N04","secret":"bbf24d4357","server":"4344","farm":5,"title":"@jyoung1220 is sad the @yankees just struck out the @redsox - I'm indifferent because I found a #vegan burger!!","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36510603975","owner":"144177933@N06","secret":"92fe929c5b","server":"4386","farm":5,"title":"DSC_7034","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36510604995","owner":"155789479@N08","secret":"56aec6225d","server":"4338","farm":5,"title":"598e4925dc623","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0},{"id":"36510606325","owner":"106637009@N08","secret":"006f622a36","server":"4357","farm":5,"title":"IMG_9058","ispublic":1,"isfriend":0,"isfamily":0}]},"stat":"ok"})
```

My highest level pojo object is something called `PhotosList` which contains a `photos` and `stat` attribute. When I make the api call from my app is am getting an error so I'm wondering if the "jsonFlickrApi(" that appears in front of the json is messing anything up. Is this possible?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: @Vanna yup! Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get correct JSON object from flickr API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24671709/how-to-get-correct-json-object-from-flickr-api)