# Content-Type header not being set with Angular $http

Tags: angularjs, xmlhttprequest, http-headers

I'm trying to make a cross-origin POST request using Angular $http with the following code.

```
//I've tried setting and removing these http config options
$http.defaults.useXDomain = true;
delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
$http.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';

//Basic request, with some private headers removed
return $http({
    method: 'POST',
    //withCredentials:true,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'},
    params: params,
    url: url
});
```

The preflight OPTIONS request gets a `200 OK`, but the subsequent POST receives a `400 Bad Request` response. Looking at the trace in Chrome's debug window, I do not see a `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` header for the POST. I assume this is why the the server is returning a Bad Request response.

I'm setting some other custom headers that I have omitted form the code above, and they are being sent and displayed fine.

I should also mention that I can make this request using the Advanced Rest Client app for Chrome and receive the correct response. (An access token)

I have also tried just doing a straight-up XMLHttpRequest(), but I get the same errors.

Any insight on why my Content-Type header is not being set?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular, content type is not being sent with $http](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194442/angular-content-type-is-not-being-sent-with-http)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not sure the `Content-Type` header will be sent if you are NOT sending any data.  Add a `data` object and try it:

```
return $http({
    method: 'POST',
    //withCredentials:true,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'},
    data: data,
    url: url
});
```

Also, usually with a post you use `data` instead of `params` (get).

You can also refer to this SO question that has some more info on how to transform the data if you need to:  [How can I post data as form data instead of a request payload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442632/how-can-i-make-angular-js-post-data-as-form-data-instead-of-a-request-payload)

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I realize that now. The header shows up when I pass some data. Still getting a `400 Bad Request`, though. So I guess the question is answered, but I'm still getting the same response. Not sure what is going on.

Comment: Your question was about the Content-Type.  If you have a separate question about the 400 request, create a new one with the specific code bits (server and client).  My guess is you aren't sending the token with the request (in the header???)

Comment: I'm sending data and it's still not being set.

Answer (score 7):

The 'Content-Type' header is not being added to the request if the data property is undefined, you can send empty string as data "" for example.

```
 var req = {
                method: 'GET',
                url: '<your url here>',
                //headers: {
                //    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
                //},
                data: ""
            };
  $http(req);
```

Answer (score 2):

I face the same issue, while setting the headers. we need to send data parameter in the `$http` request like this

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json},
    data: {},
    url: url
});
```

we can send blank data also. it will work fine.

Comment: data parameter is compulsory

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I was setting the `data` variable to an object instead of a string.

```
return $http({
    method: 'POST',
    //withCredentials:true,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'},
    data: {'key1':'value1', 'key2':'value2'},
    url: url
});
```

Once I changed it to `data:'key1=value1&key2=value2'` it worked fine. There was also a backslash in there that I had to manually put in the `%5c` code for.

Comment: You can also transofmr it on the request.  See the answer with 60 upvotes (5th one down) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442632/how-can-i-make-angular-js-post-data-as-form-data-instead-of-a-request-payload

Answer (score 1):

Than you very much "Liran B " your fix worked like a champ for me.... issue was bugging me from several hours....

```
var req = {
                method: 'GET',
                url: '<your url here>',
                //headers: {
                //    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
                //},
                data: ""
            };

  $http(req);
```