# No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'Product' from content with media type 'text/plain'

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I Recieve "No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'Product' from content with media type 'text/plain'" Error in Console when i try to post my Form data to a JSON File using ASP.NET WEBAPI

I am not posting my html file here as there are no errors in html. The error comes when the request is posted.

Please help me as i am stuck now and can't proceed ahead.

Controller calling Post Method:

```
var promisePost = crudService.post(Product);        
promisePost.then(function (pl) {   
    $scope.ProductName = pl.data.ProductName;   
    //loadRecords();   
}, function (err) {   
    console.log("Err" + err);   
});
```

Post Method in Service:

```
this.post = function (Product) {  
    var request = $http({  
        method: "post",  
        url: "http://localhost:50326/api/Products/",  
        data: Product,  
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'  
        //Content-Type: application/json  
    });  
    return request;   
}
```

WebApi Method:

```
public void Post([FromBody]Product product)  
{  
    ProductsRepository repository = new ProductsRepository();  
    var newproduct = repository.Save(product);    
    //return newproduct;  
}  

internal Product Save(Product product)  
{  
    var products = this.Retrieve();  
    var maxId = products.Max(p => p.ProductId);  
    product.ProductId = maxId + 1;  
    products.Add(product);  
    WriteData(products);  
    return product;  
}

private bool WriteData(List<Product> products)  
{  
    var filePath =   HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/App_Data/Products.json");  

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(products,   Formatting.Indented);  
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filePath, json);  

    return true;  
}
```

Comment: Your error message and your code don't match up, it's complaining that the content is `text/plain`, but based on your post code it should be `application/json`.  Have you used something like fiddler to inspect the actual POST request to verify that it's being delivered properly?

Comment: Yes. I used Fiddler to inspect my POST Request and in that i am able to see that my request is in proper format and i can the JSON of that also. The problem happens in .then( ) function i guess
promisePost.then(function (pl) {       
    $scope.ProductName = pl.data.ProductName;       
    //loadRecords();       
}

Comment: Did you inspect the `Content-Type` header?  I suspect it happens in your `then` because that is what gets the 500 error from the API?

Comment: The Error in Console says "POST http://localhost:50326/api/Products/ 500 (Internal Server Error)"

Comment: The Content type in the response is Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 whereas in the request it is Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8. It is strange how it is text/plain as we have explicitly specifies to be of type application/json

Comment: There-in lies your problem, I think the problem is this `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' ` I can't find anything that indicates that this is an acceptable way of setting the content type (but my anguar is old and rusty so I could be wrong).

Comment: So can you please specify any other way of setting the content type?

Comment: See if this question helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194442/angular-content-type-is-not-being-sent-with-http

Answer (score 0):

Try posting your data in this way:

```
$http.post(
   'http://localhost:50326/api/Products/',
   JSON.stringify(Product),
   { 
      headers: { 
         'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
   }
);
```

Note that you don't need to specify the char encoding (I've never seen that part included in the Contet-Type header. Please see this: [What does "Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8" really mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254891/what-does-content-type-application-json-charset-utf-8-really-mean))

Note also that serialize your parameter as JSON using `JSON.stringify` to ensure the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

In API Formatter

```
SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));
SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain"));
```