# Pre-flight Request not triggered for CORS check

Tags: angularjs, cors, xmlhttprequest, angular-http, preflight

As I understand, a pre-flight request is sent by the browser if any of the following conditions is **false** (source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Simple_requests):

- Request method is GET, HEAD or POST.
- Custom headers are not set.
- Content-Type header value is either `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data` or `text/plain`.

I have a web app which sends a GET request to a server on a different origin. Since I have to send cookies to the server, the property `withCredentials` is set to `true`. The header `Content-Type` is set to `application/json`. For this request, the browser does not trigger a pre-flight request, but it should because the third condition is false. What could be the reason behind this? Does it have anything to do with the insignificance of `Content-Type` header for a GET request (since there is no request body)?

EDIT: Adding request code:

```
configObject = {
  'withCredentials': true,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
};

function getRequest(url, dict) {
  $http.get(url, Object.assign({}, configObject)).success(function(result) {
    // on success
  }).error(function(err) {
    // on error
  });
  // return
}
```

Comment: You’ll need to post your request code if you want insight from others here — because it sounds like your actual code’s not doing what’s described in the question. If the code is initiating a cross-origin request and the code making the request is actually setting the Content-Type header to application/json, then that absolutely will trigger the browser to perform a preflight. Always.

Comment: @sideshowbarker I doubt the header is being actually set. When I inspect the request (in the Network tab of the browser), this header is not present in the request headers. Added the code now.

Comment: Yeah, I’m not sure why the code is using 'Object.assign({}, configObject)' as the second parameter to that .get call rather than just 'configObject', but I guess you might want to try it with just '$http.get(url, configObject)'. And if that doesn’t cause the header to be set as expected then I really have no idea. Personally, I’d recommend instead just using the standard fetch method…

Comment: @sideshowbarker That was indeed the problem. Angular was removing this header in absence of a request body. Can you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your frontend code is initiating a cross-origin request and the code making the request actually sets the `Content-Type` header to `application/json`, then that’ll absolutely trigger the browser to do a preflight. Always.

So that means, in the case in the question, the reason the browser isn’t getting triggered to do a preflight is that the header isn’t actually getting added to the request the browser ends up sending.

But the particular case described in the question is… odd — because it’s trying to add a `Content-Type` header to a *`GET` request*, and the `GET` request in the question (like pretty much all other `GET` requests) doesn’t have a request body.

And so what the cause comes down to in this case is that Angular, for `$http` calls, automatically does something arguably kind of smart (if unexpected): In the absence of a request body, it removes the `Content-Type` header from the request — which makes some good sense, because if there’s no request body, there’s no need to have a header specifying its media type.

See the accepted answer at *[Angular, content type is not being sent with $http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194442/angular-content-type-is-not-being-sent-with-http/16195104#16195104)* for confirmation of that.

And so, if for some reason you really need to include the `Content-Type` header in a request having no request body, then the solution is either to not use Angular’s `$http` at all — and instead use, say, the standard Fetch API, which will allow you to include the `Content-Type` even for requests lacking a request body — or else (in case you also have some requirement to use Angular’s `$http`) to pass in an empty request body as part of the `$http` request (by adding `data: ''` to the request).